# Asp.Net MVC ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, extension-methods

Can anyone explain why the following happens? And how to resolve, Visual Studio 2010 and MVC2

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Add New Option", "AddOption", "Product", new { @class = "lighbox" }, null)%>
```

Results in

> /Product/AddOption?class=lightbox

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Add New Option", "AddOption", "Product", new { @class = "lighbox" })%>
```

Results in

> /Product/AddOption?Length=7

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're using these respective overloads:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
string linkText,
string actionName,
string controllerName,
Object routeValues,
Object htmlAttributes
)
```

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
string linkText,
string actionName,
Object routeValues,
Object htmlAttributes
)
```

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx

The first `new { @class = "lighbox" }` is passed as the `routeValues` argument when it should be the `htmlAttributes` argument.

This sort of problem is common with the extension methods used in MVC. In can sometimes help to use ***named arguments*** (C# 4.0) to make things more readable:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Add New Option", 
   actionName: "AddOption",
   controllerName: "Product", 
   htmlAttributes: new { @class = "lighbox" }, 
   routeValues: null)%>
```

Answer (score 10):

This is an example of "overload hell" in ASP.NET MVC.

The first code calls the following method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

whereas the second code calls this one:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Notice that the string parameter `controllerName` in the first call is becoming `routeValues` in the second one. The string value "Product" is being passed to the routed values: the string property `Length` is used, which has a length of 7 here, hence the "Length=7" you're getting in the route.

Considering the first method, it seems that you've swapped the `routeValues` and `htmlAttributes` parameters.